# Unable to locate and change CloudKit Discoverability Message

Tags: ios, cloudkit, discoverability

When person first uses my app they're confronted with message:

```
"Allow people using “myApp” to look you up by email?
People who know your email address will be able to see that you use this app."
```

Buttons: Don’t Allow, OK
I'd like to change it but can't find the UIAlert setting it. Has anyone been able to change this? 
I know this is vague question and yes this could be anywhere because you don't know controllers and layout of my app, but if there's a general place to look that would be helpful. Even keyword searching doesn't find it, which makes me wonder if there is no way to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a system controlled message/alert and you have no way to change probably for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, too bad the message is a bit rough and it would've been nice to make it more friendly.